# invalid use of template name without an argument list

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, linked-list

I am facing a problem with my linked list class, I have created the interface and implementation files of the class, but when I build it, this error occurs: "invalid use of template name 'LinkedList' without an argument list".
here's my interface file:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

template <typename T>
struct Node{
    T info;
    Node<T> *next;
};

template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
    Node<T> *start;
    Node<T> *current;
public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
};

#endif // LINKEDLIST_H
```

and this is my implementation code:

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
   start = nullptr;
   current = nullptr;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
  {

  }
```

Comment: `template<typename T> LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()` and implement it in header

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
{
   start = nullptr;
   current = nullptr;
}
```

And similarly for other member functions. But you'll run into another problem - declarations and definitions of a template [can't be separated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) to different files.

Comment: I have done it, but as you said, there is an error with the declaration of 'NULL', it says that NULL was not declared in this scope. how can I solve this issue??

Comment: @Alladinsaoudi NULL is a macro that's defined in several different headers listed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL). You'll have to include at least one of them where you want to use it.

Comment: @jrol thanks a looooooooooot , i do really appreciate your help. :))))

Comment: @Alladinsaoudi With C++11 better use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. Moreover, you can always simply use `0` instead of `NULL` (but `nullptr` is better as the compiler can make some checks).

Comment: Anyone using C++11 or above should now use `nullptr`.

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that sometimes the library already provides a specialization for the class you want to use, like a `Vector3` that could be used as `Vector3<double>` or `Vector3d`